# Dry roasting nuts and spices beforehand

Tags: spices, nuts, coconut, peanuts, toasting

I have recipes that call for dry roasting peanuts, coconut, and sesame seeds.
I make these recipes a lot — so theoretically it would be easier to dry roast everything I have one time, instead of each time I'm making a dish. Would that in any way diminish the taste of the dish?  And does the same apply to spices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properly stored, dry roasted nuts should lose none of their flavour. Keep them in a well sealed container and they will be fine.

Spices, however, should be freshly toasted, because the point of doing so is to encourage them to release their flavourful oils.

Comment: I agree, and I think coconut should be freshly toasted as for the spices.

Comment: I've worked at bakeries that toasted our coconut beforehand (not too far though, usually a week, no more than a month), and it suffered no ill effects.